# Transition property background-image not working on Firefox (using prefix)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, transition

I have a div that when I hover over it should change the background image from one to another. It works flawlessly on chrome, and it is not working at all on firefox or IE.

I have checked throughout the relevant MDN reference page and tried several different options, but I could not find the answer to my problem so I am trying here to see if anyone encountered the same behaviour, and eventually knows the solution.

Here a link to see what is going on: http://codepen.io/thevalent/pen/RWqWGJ?editors=110

And this is the css side:

```
#wrapper{
    background-image: url(dropText.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15em;
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
  }
#wrapper:hover{
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    background-image: url(uploadPic.png);
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

I tried to replace background-image property with "all" but again it works just on chrome. Also as you can see on the link above, if I change it to background-color, it works with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions are applied to *animatable* properties, [per the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties). The `background-image` property is *not* animatable, [per the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image). 
As such, Firefox and Internet Explorer are both spec-compliant. Chrome may be exploring non-spec/proprietary functionality.

There are some ideas for the future on how developers and designers ought to be able to transition images. You can start your study of those ideas by reading [CSS Image Transitions](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/fx/wiki/CSS_Image_Transitions).

Tab Atkins briefly discusses the `cross-fade` function in his [Future of CSS](https://youtu.be/ad1Wq0qZrMQ?t=273) presentations.

Comment: Thank you for the resources, I will try to come up with a different solution then. To be fair I thought about the possibility of overlapping two divs and try to play around with their opacity properties, fading one in and the other out. At the end of the day that's what Chrome browser is doing. Do you think it could work?

Comment: I didn't notice the related Q&A, my bad. It works though, also it seems that Chrome is handling automatically width and height properties so to seamlessly transition from one image to another.